# Disabling after onclick addClass

Tags: jquery, onclick, toggle

I'm really new to jQuery. I've grab some code for my wordpress menu from some tutorial but I want to add some customization to it. So what I'm looking for is when the li with a class of "has-sub" is clicked and it adds the class of "open" I would like the other li elements event if it doesn't have a class of "has-sub" to add a class of "disabled". My purpose is to gray it out the other menu items with css styling so it focuses on what was click. Is this possible. Here is the jquery code I have.

```
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('click', function(){
  $(this).removeAttr('href');
  var element = $(this).parent('li');
  if (element.hasClass('open')) {
    element.removeClass('open');
    element.find('li').removeClass('open');
    element.find('ul').hide();

  }
  else {
    element.addClass('open');
    element.children('ul').show();
    element.siblings('li').children('ul').hide();
    element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
    element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
    element.siblings('li').find('ul').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't sound right. Let's say you have a list of links in blue color. I click on one and it becomes red (added class "open" that makes it red) but why would I make all my links gray? Are they not click-able anymore? I think what you wish to do is remove open class from all links and add it to only the clicked one. So this way only one, the clicked one, link will be red.

Comment: So you basically want to "highlight" a clicked element... Can you post the rendered stucture? and the CSS classes you have in mind...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is just a matter of adding and removing CSS classes.

On click, add a `greyed` and remove a `highlighted` on all elements..
The inverse for the clicked element.

If you just improve the styling (felt like no effort in this demo) of two classes toggling... You have a starter.

Something like:

```js
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub a').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".has-sub").removeClass("highlighted").addClass("greyed");
  $(this).parents(".has-sub").addClass("highlighted").removeClass("greyed");
});
```

```css
a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:black;
}
.highlighted{
  background-color:cyan;
}
.highlighted a{
  color:red;
}
.greyed{
  background-color:#bbb;
}
.greyed a{
  color:#444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="cssmenu">
  <li class="has-sub">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Anchor</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Anchor</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Anchor</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Anchor</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-sub">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Anchor</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Anchor</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Anchor</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Anchor</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-sub">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Anchor</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Anchor</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Anchor</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Anchor</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Some of my links will not have a submenu under them but I think this got me to the right direction thanks